# jenkins maven fails after upgrading to mvn 3.6.2

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I updated maven from 3.6.1 to 3.6.2 and now a jenkins job fails when maven runs a 'clean deploy' script with the following error.  the deploy copies the war file to Sonatype nexus on the same server.  the only change that has been made is updating /usr/share/maven from 3.6.1 to 3.6.2

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project

Adding '-e' to the maven script shows the root exception as: 
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connection reset by peer (Write failed)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put
```

Comment: it could be possible that new update doesn't have the same `settings.xml` (happens to be in $MAVEN_HOME/conf/ ) in case you are using global setting and configured maven as tool in jenkins. ref: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: This is a network issue: `Connection reset by peer (Write failed)`...maybe something other but based on the limited informations it's hard to guess. What version of JDK, Jenkins? How exactly you are calling it from Jenkins ? Pipeline?

Comment: @old-monk you are correct.  Somehow the settings.xml file was overwitten and I had to re-enter the credentials for nexus.  One I did that everything worked properly